# How to properly spread an object with useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Currently toggling between light and dark theme for a school project: (https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-overflow-dark-theme-light-theme-xh0s4). However, anytime the user toggles with the button, the theme object is overwritten (E.G. No primary and secondary colors). The state and function looks like this...

```js
const [theme, setTheme] = useState({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#FF0000",
      light: "#E7F6E7",
      contrastText: "#FFFFFF"
    },
    secondary: {
      main: "#FFFFFF"
    },
    type: "light"
  }
});

const toggleTheme = () => {
  let newPaletteType = theme.palette.type === "light" ? "dark" : "light";
  setTheme({
    ...theme,
    palette: {
      type: newPaletteType
    }
  });
  console.log(theme);
};
```

I was curious how I should be spreading state with this object... Thanks!

Comment: Looks ok to me? What is the issue here?

Answer (score 2):

You need to spread the `palette` object back into itself too.

```js
const toggleTheme = () => {
  let newPaletteType = theme.palette.type === "light" ? "dark" : "light";
  setTheme({
    ...theme,
    palette: {
      ...theme.palette, // here
      type: newPaletteType
    }
  });
};
```

When you modify one key of the object, you need to replace the others if you want to keep them. When you use the spread operator, you are no longer actually modifying the original object, but creating a new one based on the values of the original. However, on nested objects, just doing the parent isn't enough.

So for instance, if you changed a key in `primary`, you'd need to do it at alll three nested levels.

```js
setTheme({
  ...theme,
  palette: {
    ...theme.palette,
    primary: {
      ...theme.palette.primary,
      //change value in primary
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Brian mentioned, you will have to explicitly spread back the object that you are trying to edit.

```
const toggleTheme = () => {
  let newPaletteType = theme.palette.type === "light" ? "dark" : "light";
  const newPalette = { ...theme.palette, type: newPaletteType };
  setTheme({
    ...theme,
    palette: newPalette,
  });
  console.log(theme);
};
```

You can define another variable to make it more readable.